# Close vote review queue showing unrelated close type question as an audit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, review-audits

While working on the Close Vote review queue today I selected "Opinion-based" to narrow the type of reviewing I was doing. The first question presented was a "details or clarity" type of closure question which was quite obvious as being an audit.

If you are going to show me an audit question at least show me one of the same type as the type of reviewing I have selected to make it less obvious.

Comment: Congratulations, you were paying attention! Audits are designed to catch robo reviewers, the kind that would miss something as obvious as that. This is *not a bug*.